# JQuery Sortable, optimize code for multiple input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 10 text input fields, each one working with select2 and jquery sortable.

Actually, to have sortable function for each field, I've duplicated code for each one and it works well. But as you can understand, I would optimize it to use with N fields.

My code:

```
    // Sortable
    jQuery("#_posts_1").select2("container").find("ul.select2-choices").sortable({
        containment: "parent", 
        start: function() { jQuery("#_posts_1").select2("onSortStart"); },  
        update: function() { jQuery("#_posts_1").select2("onSortEnd"); } });
    jQuery("#_posts_1").on("change", function() { jQuery("#_posts_1").html(jQuery("#_posts_1").val());});

    [... the same code for each field ...]

    jQuery("#_posts_10").select2("container").find("ul.select2-choices").sortable({
        containment: "parent", 
        start: function() { jQuery("#_posts_10").select2("onSortStart"); }, 
        update: function() { jQuery("#_posts_10").select2("onSortEnd"); } });
    jQuery("#_posts_10").on("change", function() { jQuery("#_posts_10").html(jQuery("#_posts_10").val());});
```

How can I optimize in unique function?
Thanks

Comment: Why not use a class instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("[id^='_posts_'").each(function(i,elem){
        $(elem).select2("container").find("ul.select2-choices").sortable({
        containment: "parent", 
        start: function() { $(elem).select2("onSortStart"); },  
        update: function() { $(elem).select2("onSortEnd"); } });
    $(elem).on("change", function() { $(elem).html($(elem).val());});
});
```

Comment: Although you should probably rewrite the .on as well, but I would need to know the name of a container of the posts to do so.  I could use body, but it would be better not to.